# Where can I find large graph test datasets with independent number equals to 2?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms, independence

I want to test some conjecture in graphs with independent number equals to 2. Where can I find them?

Or if you know a way to generate such graphs.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: A nice fully searchable database is given in the [House of Graphs project](https://hog.grinvin.org/). I am not aware of a generation algorithm for generating graphs with a fixed independence set number. However, you could brute-force and just generate all graphs up to isomorphism using the geng generator implemented in SageMath and filter for the desired property. You can find the reference for sage [here](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/graph_generators.html). Reference on how to calculate the independence set number can be found in the same documentation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am not an expert, so not sure how helpful this is - but why not start from an empty graph with, say, $n$ vertices and, in each iteration, pick a random $3$-anticlique and add a random edge to it until there are no more $3$-anticliques?

Comment: Take the complete graph $K_n$ and add to it one new vertex and $k$ ($k<n$) edges coming from that vertex. You will get a graph with independent number equals to  two.

Comment: Thanks guys. House of Graph dataset worked for me well.

Comment: It may help to know that the complements of such graphs are the triangle-free graphs, which are more well-studied.